# Does a non-concurrent bag exist

Tags: c#

Is there such a thing as a non-concurrent bag? I see lots of mentions of `ConcurrentBag`, but nothing about `Bag`.

Does such a collection exist?

To clarify why I'd like to use such a collection, I often find that the order of a collection becomes an important but potentially difficult to trace property of a collection.

I'm not necessarily saying that this would often happen in good, well designed code, but there are situations where I wish I could say "do not expect any order on this collection, order it specifically as and when you need to".

Comment: It's called by another name.  `HashSet`  Or if you want ordered, `List`.  No, there is no class named `Bag`.

Comment: @Amy Not true? `ConcurrentBag` supports duplicates, while a `HashSet` explicitly doesn't

Comment: @Amy yes, though I'm looking for something which supports duplicates

Comment: it implements IReadOnlyCollection<T> interface. So probably that is a non thread-safe representation?

Comment: @OliverRadini A bag is a collection with no specific implementation. What properties do you expect a Bag class to have? How is it different from a List?

Comment: What would a non-concurrent bag give you that a simple `Stack<T>` or `List<T>` doesn't? Given that the order of items doesn't matter.

Comment: @Richiban I'm looking for something which has no order, but supports duplicates

Comment: @Richiban Well of course, a `List<T>` or a `Stack<T>` both support dupes.

Comment: `List`, `Stack,` `Queue` and many other classes could all serve as things that meet the `Bag` contract. If you don't care about  the order, it shouldn't matter that there *is* an order; if you care about the order being "nondeterministic" or "random", you're looking at something that's more than just a bag (but could still easily be implemented *using* one of those classes; stick a `Random.Next(count)` in the `Take` and away you go).

Comment: ConcurrentBag is a special-purpose collection that stores data in thread-local storage, making it cheap to read a thread's one data, expensive to read another thread's. There's no concurrent equivalent to that. If you want something that has no order, why not a List, Stack or Queue? What characteristics are you looking for?

Comment: [ExpandoObject?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think it does matter; when you have an unordered collection, you have no reason to expect that it has any order whatsoever. If I have a list, I don't know whether or not any other parts of the code are expecting it to be in a particular order

Comment: So you want something that's unordered until it isn't?

Comment: @RobertHarvey precisely!

Comment: ArrayList is sortable.

Comment: I've heard of "no requirement that the collection is ordered" but I've never heard of a "requirement that the collection is unordered"!

Comment: To do what you want you need something very limited indeed, like a `CopyTo` method that takes an `IComparer` and produces the entire collection sorted on demand -- and *only* that way, so the caller cannot (say) get an `IEnumerable` and fetch the elements one by one, lest they are again relying on some kind of hidden or implicit order. It's possible, but I don't think it's really worth doing. Depending on why you think it's important to enforce the restriction, there are probably easier (and less performance-killing) ways.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ArrayList is deprecated or at least Microsoft "[doesn't] recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development". List<T> is also sortable.

Comment: @Richiban It does seem to be an unusual idea, most probably I'm missing something.  It seems to me that this is just an example of trying to only expose what it required. I think we could all think of many other examples where we gain an advantage in terms of reasonability by restricting the interfaces we use, but in this case it seems that order is seen as something that is seen as being a requisite of a collection of non-unique data.

Comment: It's actually more subtle than that -- the "problem" (if you can call it that) is that C# is a sequential, imperative language. Whether or not you consider a collection to have an order, any code you write operating on all elements of the collection will, in one way or another, be relying on an order, by virtue of having instructions that run in order. This is true even if the collection promises no order; you would need to excise any and all methods of getting elements piecemeal, but that in turn would make the collection far less useful.

Comment: @OliverRadini In a language such as C# order of a collection will always be an implementation detail; there's no way for an interface to declare that implementers define an order for their elements. Stick to any of the collection interfaces and you should be fine. The only caveat to that is that exposing an indexer with an integer key *strongly* implies positional order to the elements within.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's an interesting perspective; though I must say, whilst we can agree that a collection may have an order in memory, it doesn't need to have one when represented as code. Many parts of the underlying processes are already abstracted, or obfuscated, so I see no reason why it shouldn't be at least possible in this instance

Comment: @Richiban but `ConcurrentBag` is an unordered collection, right?

Comment: Correct, as an implementation detail is does have an order, it just doesn't define what that is to its consumers. It does, however, have an order that could be predicted if you had enough information about the system when creating an modifying the collection. Slightly off-topic. Anyway, my answer to your question would be to either define your own Bag type that is simply a wrapper around a `List`, or expose your 'Bag' as an interface, such as `ICollection` (if you need mutability)

Comment: Like I said, you could have a method that offers the collection *only* with a user-supplied order (`IOrderedEnumerable<T> GetElements(IComparer<T> comparer)`), which forces the caller to specify a way to order the elements on every call, but unless you stick in something like caching this would be madly inefficient. This is why a practical, unordered collection would stick to implementing `IEnumerable` with the note that the order is undefined (which is what `Dictionary` does).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but since it [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8) as being "optimized for scenarios where the same thread will be both producing and consuming data stored in the bag",  you can just use ConcurrentBag in both concurrent and non-concurrent scenarios.

Comment: Thank you; this certainly answers the question. I think, in this case, there is not a collection which really does what I was looking to do

Comment: Yes.  It's hard to prevent developers from taking a dependency on the observed ordering of a collection.  This is a common source of bugs in SQL Server applciations, and there's an example in the .NET Framework where the order of Properties returned by Reflection is not guaranteed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your own class that "hides" the order of the items.

For example:

```
public sealed class NonConcurrentBag<T>: IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        // When adding an item, add it to a random location to avoid callers assuming an ordering.

        if (_items.Count == 0)
        {
            _items.Add(item);
            return;
        }

        int index = _rng.Next(0, _items.Count);
        _items.Add(_items[index]);
        _items[index] = item;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _items.Clear();
    }

    public T Take()
    {
        if (_items.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempting to Take() from an empty NonConcurrentBag");

        var result = _items[_items.Count - 1];
        _items.RemoveAt(_items.Count - 1);

        return result;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty => _items.Count == 0;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count => _items.Count;

    readonly List<T> _items = new List<T>();

    readonly Random _rng = new Random();
}
```

When you add an item, this sneakily adds it at a random index (shifting the displaced item to the end of the list).

That means that not only is the index of an item random when you add it, it can also move to a different index as you add more items. That'll foil anything that expects any particular order!

Adding and taking items is an O(1) operation except when adding and the underlying list needs to be resized, when it is an O(N) operation.

Comment: Why IReadOnlyCollection<T> and not ICollection<T> considering you already have Add and Clear from ICollection and Remove and Contains wouldn't violate bag semantics?

Comment: @ckuri Because I was modelling this on [`ConcurrentBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8), which implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` but not `ICollection<T>` (although I omitted [`IProducerConsumerCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) because I didn't think it was worth spending the time to add that for this sample code).